# ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby") returns NULL

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I have researched a lot but could not find the up to date material about the use of JRuby in Java. I am implementing this code and it returns null when I run:

Here is my code:

`ScriptEngine blah = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby")`

I'm sure that the classpaths are correct and I've done the setup correct.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hava you set `System.setProperty("jruby.home","/opt/local/share/java/jruby");` to your jruby path?

Comment: Yea I tried before but I did it again just to make sure and nothing changed. I've tried with .getEngineByName("JavaScript") and that works fine.